# Stripe error with price - Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, strapi

I know this has been asked before but my scenario is a bit different. Basically if an item is 18.99 for instance, I get the above error. However if the price is say 20.00, the checkout works. I can't figure out where I have to do modify the code. I am setting the price in the Strapi CMS. Thanks in advance for any pointers here.

Here is my order.js (server side)

```
"use strict";
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

/**
 * order controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::order.order", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async create(ctx) {
    const { products, userName, email } = ctx.request.body;
    try {
      // retrieve item information
      const lineItems = await Promise.all(
        products.map(async (product) => {
          const item = await strapi
            .service("api::item.item")
            .findOne(product.id);

          return {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: item.name,
              },
              unit_amount: item.price,
            },
            quantity: product.count,
          };
        })
      );

      // create a stripe session
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        customer_email: email,
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: "http://localhost:3000/checkout/success",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000",
        line_items: lineItems,
      });

      // create the item
      await strapi
        .service("api::order.order")
        .create({ data: { userName, products, stripeSessionId: session.id } });

      // return the session id
      return { id: session.id };
    } catch (error) {
      ctx.response.status = 500;
      return { error: { message: "There was a problem creating the charge" } };
    }
  },
}));
```

Here is my Checkout.jsx (front end)

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { Box, Button, Stepper, Step, StepLabel } from "@mui/material"
import { Formik } from "formik"
import { useState } from "react"
import * as yup from "yup"
import { shades } from "../../theme"
import Payment from "./Payment"
import Shipping from "./Shipping"
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
    "xxxxxx"
)

const Checkout = () => {
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0)
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cart)
    const isFirstStep = activeStep === 0
    const isSecondStep = activeStep === 1

    const handleFormSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
        setActiveStep(activeStep + 1)

        // this copies the billing address onto shipping address
        if (isFirstStep && values.shippingAddress.isSameAddress) {
            actions.setFieldValue("shippingAddress", {
                ...values.billingAddress,
                isSameAddress: true
            })
        }

        if (isSecondStep) {
            makePayment(values)
        }

        actions.setTouched({})
    }

    async function makePayment(values) {
        const stripe = await stripePromise
        const requestBody = {
            userName: [values.firstName, values.lastName].join(" "),
            email: values.email,
            products: cart.map(({ id, count }) => ({
                id,
                count
            }))
        }

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/orders", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
        })
        const session = await response.json()
        await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: session.id
        })
    }

    return (
        <Box width="80%" m="100px auto">
            <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} sx={{ m: "20px 0" }}>
                <Step>
                    <StepLabel>Billing</StepLabel>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <StepLabel>Payment</StepLabel>
                </Step>
            </Stepper>
            <Box>
                <Formik
                    onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
                    initialValues={initialValues}
                    validationSchema={checkoutSchema[activeStep]}>
                    {({
                        values,
                        errors,
                        touched,
                        handleBlur,
                        handleChange,
                        handleSubmit,
                        setFieldValue
                    }) => (
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            {isFirstStep && (
                                <Shipping
                                    values={values}
                                    errors={errors}
                                    touched={touched}
                                    handleBlur={handleBlur}
                                    handleChange={handleChange}
                                    setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                                />
                            )}
                            {isSecondStep && (
                                <Payment
                                    values={values}
                                    errors={errors}
                                    touched={touched}
                                    handleBlur={handleBlur}
                                    handleChange={handleChange}
                                    setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                                />
                            )}
                            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" gap="50px">
                                {!isFirstStep && (
                                    <Button
                                        fullWidth
                                        color="primary"
                                        variant="contained"
                                        sx={{
                                            backgroundColor: shades.primary[200],
                                            boxShadow: "none",
                                            color: "white",
                                            borderRadius: 0,
                                            padding: "15px 40px"
                                        }}
                                        onClick={() => setActiveStep(activeStep - 1)}>
                                        Back
                                    </Button>
                                )}
                                <Button
                                    fullWidth
                                    type="submit"
                                    color="primary"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    sx={{
                                        backgroundColor: shades.primary[400],
                                        boxShadow: "none",
                                        color: "white",
                                        borderRadius: 0,
                                        padding: "15px 40px"
                                    }}>
                                    {!isSecondStep ? "Next" : "Place Order"}
                                </Button>
                            </Box>
                        </form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}

const initialValues = {
    billingAddress: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        country: "",
        street1: "",
        street2: "",
        city: "",
        state: "",
        zipCode: ""
    },
    shippingAddress: {
        isSameAddress: true,
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        country: "",
        street1: "",
        street2: "",
        city: "",
        state: "",
        zipCode: ""
    },
    email: "",
    phoneNumber: ""
}

const checkoutSchema = [
    yup.object().shape({
        billingAddress: yup.object().shape({
            firstName: yup.string().required("required"),
            lastName: yup.string().required("required"),
            country: yup.string().required("required"),
            street1: yup.string().required("required"),
            street2: yup.string(),
            city: yup.string().required("required"),
            state: yup.string().required("required"),
            zipCode: yup.string().required("required")
        }),
        shippingAddress: yup.object().shape({
            isSameAddress: yup.boolean(),
            firstName: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            }),
            lastName: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            }),
            country: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            }),
            street1: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            }),
            street2: yup.string(),
            city: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            }),
            state: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            }),
            zipCode: yup.string().when("isSameAddress", {
                is: false,
                then: yup.string().required("required")
            })
        })
    }),
    yup.object().shape({
        email: yup.string().required("required"),
        phoneNumber: yup.string().required("required")
    })
]

export default Checkout
```

Here is the CartMenu.jsx

```
import { Box, Button, Divider, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close"
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add"
import RemoveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Remove"
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import { shades } from "../../theme"
import {
    decreaseCount,
    increaseCount,
    removeFromCart,
    setIsCartOpen
} from "../../state"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

const FlexBox = styled(Box)`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
`

const CartMenu = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cart)
    const isCartOpen = useSelector((state) => state.cart.isCartOpen)

    const totalPrice = cart.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + item.count * item.attributes.price
    }, 0)

    Math.round(totalPrice.toFixed(2) * 100)

    return (
        <Box
            display={isCartOpen ? "block" : "none"}
            backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
            position="fixed"
            zIndex={10}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            left="0"
            top="0"
            overflow="auto">
            <Box
                position="fixed"
                right="0"
                bottom="0"
                width="max(400px, 30%)"
                height="100%"
                backgroundColor="white">
                <Box padding="30px" overflow="auto" height="100%">
                    {/* HEADER */}
                    <FlexBox mb="15px">
                        <Typography variant="h3">SHOPPING BAG ({cart.length})</Typography>
                        <IconButton onClick={() => dispatch(setIsCartOpen({}))}>
                            <CloseIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </FlexBox>

                    {/* CART LIST */}
                    <Box>
                        {cart.map((item) => (
                            <Box key={`${item.attributes.name}-${item.id}`}>
                                <FlexBox p="15px 0">
                                    <Box flex="1 1 40%">
                                        <img
                                            alt={item?.name}
                                            width="123px"
                                            height="164px"
                                            src={`http://localhost:1337${item?.attributes?.image?.data?.attributes?.formats?.medium?.url}`}
                                        />
                                    </Box>
                                    <Box flex="1 1 60%">
                                        <FlexBox mb="5px">
                                            <Typography fontWeight="bold">
                                                {item.attributes.name}
                                            </Typography>
                                            <IconButton
                                                onClick={() =>
                                                    dispatch(removeFromCart({ id: item.id }))
                                                }>
                                                <CloseIcon />
                                            </IconButton>
                                        </FlexBox>
                                        <Typography>{item.attributes.shortDescription}</Typography>
                                        <FlexBox m="15px 0">
                                            <Box
                                                display="flex"
                                                alignItems="center"
                                                border={`1.5px solid ${shades.neutral[500]}`}>
                                                <IconButton
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        dispatch(decreaseCount({ id: item.id }))
                                                    }>
                                                    <RemoveIcon />
                                                </IconButton>
                                                <Typography>{item.count}</Typography>
                                                <IconButton
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        dispatch(increaseCount({ id: item.id }))
                                                    }>
                                                    <AddIcon />
                                                </IconButton>
                                            </Box>
                                            <Typography fontWeight="bold">
                                                ${item.attributes.price}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </FlexBox>
                                    </Box>
                                </FlexBox>
                                <Divider />
                            </Box>
                        ))}
                    </Box>

                    {/* ACTIONS */}
                    <Box m="20px 0">
                        <FlexBox m="20px 0">
                            <Typography fontWeight="bold">SUBTOTAL</Typography>
                            <Typography fontWeight="bold">
                                ${totalPrice.toFixed(2)}
                            </Typography>
                        </FlexBox>
                        <Button
                            sx={{
                                backgroundColor: shades.primary[400],
                                color: "white",
                                borderRadius: 0,
                                minWidth: "100%",
                                padding: "20px 40px",
                                m: "20px 0"
                            }}
                            onClick={() => {
                                navigate("/checkout")
                                dispatch(setIsCartOpen({}))
                            }}>
                            CHECKOUT
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default CartMenu
```

This is the error I am seeing in the console

```
v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
at ls (v3:1:333715)
at ps (v3:1:334004)
at ms (v3:1:334912)
at fs (v3:1:335026)
at v3:1:370022
at e.redirectToCheckout (v3:1:371693)
at makePayment (Checkout.jsx:56:1)
```

This is the line where it's failing on my Checkout.jsx

```
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/orders", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    const session = await response.json()
    await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: session.id
    })
}
```

Comment: are your prices in cents?

Comment: please edit the question and show the complete stack trace and error message in the question.

Comment: Yes, in cents. The error happens when you goto make the payment from the payment page.

Comment: As OldProgrammer suggested, please share more of the error message. Have you added debug statements to try and trace the flow? Also try logging session and session.id to see if that gives you a hint into what you're actually passing to stripe.redirectToCheckout in these cases.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that in a few hours when I can get back to it.

Comment: @codename_duchess I edited it - let me know if that provides any insight

Comment: Did you try improving your logging as suggested?

Comment: @codename_duchess all it's saying is that "there was a problem creating the charge" (in the error handling on the order.js)